# How to enable SM-X Module in cisco ISR 4451 Router

Tags: cisco, router, cisco-ios, cisco-commands, cisco-isr

While plug in a SM-X-ES3D-48-P Etherswitch Module into a Cisco ISR 4451 the Ports for this Module didn't came up. What I need to do to get the Ports enable with `sh ip int br` command?

The Output of `sh hw-module all attribute` is:

```
Slot 0 Bay 0 Board 0 Module[ISR4451-X-4x1GE] spa_type 0x76E Daughter Board Not Present
Basic attributes : length 11, version [2], module-type [ngio-virtual], width [unknown]
Power Rating [0], Control Endpoint count [0], Daughter Board Count [0]
KR Support [0x00], 16-bit GPIO [Not present], Submodule reset support [Not required]

Extended Attributes for [Front Panel 4 ports Gigabitethernet Module]
Port Count 4 Per-port Information : Type [Ethernet] Max IID [0] Connector [RJ45] Network clocking [disable]
Module OID: 1 3 6 1 4 1 9 12 3 1 9 92 21 
Port OID: 1 3 6 1 4 1 9 12 3 1 10 109 


Slot 1 Bay 0 Board 0 Module[SM-X-ES3D-48-P] spa_type 0xB4B Daughter Board Not Present
Base mac_addr 00da.55b0.e300 mac_blk_sz 128  Endpt MAC Address offset(s) : 52 
Basic attributes : length 11, version [2], module-type [alien], width [Double Wide-no aux]
Power Rating [100], Control Endpoint count [1], Daughter Board Count [0]
KR Support [0x00], 16-bit GPIO [Present], Submodule reset support [Required]

Extended Attributes for [SM-X-ES3D-48-P: EtherSwitch SM L3 + PoEPlus + MACSec + 48 10/100/1000 + 2 SFP]
GPIO Pin Information
Output Pin[Sub module reset]
Input Pin[PRI interface ready]
Output Pin[Reset config]

I2C Information
[dev_addr 0xB dev_type quack]

Port Count 2 Per-port Information : Type [Ether-Internal] Max IID [0] Connector [RJ45] Network clocking [disable]
Module OID: 1 3 6 1 4 1 9 12 3 1 9 96 6 
Port OID: 1 3 6 1 4 1 9 12 3 1 10 109
```

In the docu for this module I can't find a way to activate this 48 Ports and sh ip int br Command didn't show the Ports. What can I do?

Comment: What do you mean? Are you trying to use these switch interfaces as router interfaces? That won't work.

Comment: No I want to use this interfaces as switched interfaces but I can't see this interfaces in sh ip in br

Comment: Do you see the interfaces when you show the configuration?

Comment: No in sh run also no interfaces only the internal 4 Gi Interfaces

Comment: What can I do to add this extra Interfaces? The new interfaces are on same level as the old ones? I aspected the new Interfaces in Gi1/0/x

Comment: It was a false on my side. I need to connect directly to the SM Module. The sh ip int br command on the ISR don't show me the GI Ints from the submodule. After hw-module session 1/0 I was connected with the SM Module and can see the Interfaces.

Comment: There are 52 Interfaces on the SM-X Module and Port 51 and 52 are up but no cable are connected. What Interfaces is it?

Comment: If you have figured it out, you should post it as an answer and accept the answer, otherwise the question will keep popping up forever, looking for an answer that you already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EtherSwitch Module isn't a routing module, so you can't see the EtherSwitch Port if you connected to the ISR Router. You need to connect to the EtherSwitch module separate with following Command:

```
hw-module session 1/0
```

The Part 1/0 of above command depend from the Output of `sh hw-module all attribute` Command:

```
...
Slot 1 Bay 0 Board 0 Module[SM-X-ES3D-48-P]
...
```

1/0 is for Slot 1 Bay 0, than you connect to the EtherSwitch command and can configure this one.